# BASH: reuse argument from same command

Tags: bash

I know I can reuse the first argument from the prævious command with `!:1`; but is it possible to reuse an already typed argument from the command currently being entered? Say I want to `cp blablabla blablabla.bak` (and assume there are other similarly named files in the directory); it would be nice not to have to type blablabla all over again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes; you can use the history expansion `!#` to represent the current line so far:

```
cp blablabla !#:1.bak
```

Comment: +1; I had no idea. For the OP's specific case, by the way, another option is brace expansion: `cp blablabla{,.bak}`.